# How do I get pressing the enter key to stop being treated like a mouse click in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, button, addeventlistener

I have a program where I have several clickable buttons as well as a reason to click enter. Issue is, if I click a handful of the buttons with the mouse and then click the enter key on my keyboard, it does what enter should do and it also acts as though I had clicked the last button that I clicked one more time. I want the clicking to only be done with the mouse and have the enter key not be able to click buttons. How do I do this?
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTLBx.png)
Here is how I am currently making the buttons clickable and getting the input of the keyboard.

Comment: context, just a bit of code to work off of please

Comment: Code will definitely help (a minimal reproducible example). Do your buttons have types? If not, they default to "submit" which is triggered by the enter key.

Comment: @user1599011 Is that true? I always thought it defaults to `button`

Comment: "type: 
    The default behavior of the button. Possible values are:

        submit: The button submits the form data to the server. This is the default if the attribute is not specified for buttons associated with a <form>, or if the attribute is an empty or invalid value."
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

Comment: @Jacob, have you solved your issue? I yes, it would be nice to report back.

Answer (score 0):

By clicking on the `tile` button, it gets focus. Hence, subsequent `enter` triggers the button.

You could "un-focus" the button:

```js
// tile is a reference to the button, as per your question
tile.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
  // un-focus
  tile.blur();
  // do some stuff
});
```